# Number theory problem exercise?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find all natural numbers $N$  so that $\varphi(N)=24$ where $\varphi$  is Euler's function.

Comment: So far i got that 24=2^3*3 and i took φ(Ν)=N(1-1/p(1))*....(1-1/p(k)) where p(i) are the primes in the prime factorization of N.So having factored both sides tried to find some equalities...

Comment: Since $\varphi$ is multiplicative for relatively primes, Consider the factorization of N.

Comment: I am pretty sure I saw this problem before on this site...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint - if a prime $p$ is a factor of $N$ then you should be able to show that $p-1$ is a factor of $\varphi(n)$ and use this to identify the possible prime factors of $N$.

Comment: I found the possible prime factors of N and i examine the possible combinations of N having only 2 as factor then 2 and 3 as a factor since the power's do not count in the computation of φ(N).BUt still there are alot of combinations to examine..cause the possible prime factors of N are 2,3,5,7,11,23.....

Comment: Only thing i can say is that N=2^a1*3^a2*5^a3*7^a4*11^a5*23^a6  where a(i)>=0 and not all of them zeros.

Comment: @ManolisLyviakis - where do $11$ and $23$ come from? And consider Hamid's comment. And don't forget the prime $2$ for which $2-1=1$. Once you have the primes, consider what contribution each can make to $\varphi (N)$ - you do have to consider cases, but organise yourself to reduce this consideration to a minimum.

Comment: @ManolisLyviakis $p=13$ or $p=25$ I think ...

Comment: oh my god  i made an error on th sign you are correct im so sorry

Comment: @ManolisLyviakis It is so easy to do. I think it is a bit about noticing when it happens to you, and being a bit conscious next time. Catch it before it happens in an exam ... !

Comment: I will!By the way i think i found the sollutions and a way to find them..after you find the possible prime divisors of N i took for example 13|N so N=13*y where (y,13)=1 and said φ(Ν)=φ(13)*φ(y) so 24=12*φ(y) so φ(y)=2 so doing same thing for y i found y=3,6,4 so N=78,39,52 did same thing for the rest possible primes..